# Editing asp.net core identity claims instead of adding them

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identity, claims, asp.net-authorization

I'm using external logins for my asp.net core mvc website, and when the login completes I want to store the social info they used to login (such as username, profile image, etc.) as claims in the user's identity...

So I run code like this in my account controller after a successful login:

```
    var authClaim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClaimType == authToken.Name);
    if (authClaim == null)
          externalClaims.Add(new Claim(authToken.Name, authToken.Value));
    else
          authClaim.ClaimValue = authToken.Value;

    if (externalClaims.Any())
          await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(user, externalClaims);

await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```

however when I attempt to do this, the claims table is duplicating the claims rather than updating them as I expected, so every time the user logs in I get another collection of records in the table for that user that are identical to the last.

do I have to delete them and re-add them instead on every login? if not, how do I update existing claims without duplicating them?

I'm doing it on every login in case the user has changed their profile or other info (and to make sure I have the most up to date token).

I'm also curious why I add the claims to the main Identity of the user. The User has a property called **ExternalClaims**, but it is empty and there doesn't appear to be any way to update it. It seems to me this is a better place to put these third-party Claims, but I can't for the life of me find any way to modify it...

either way, I'm sure I'd have the same problem if I use this code, so is the proper course to delete the claim on login and always add it new, or should I be doing something differently?

Comment: Are you using the UserManager class from the project templates, or do you have a custom implementation?

Comment: It does appear that there is a method called [ReplaceClaimAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs) that might better fit for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: oooo this looks like just what I need! I am using the built in usermanager class, let me try this and report back, many thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I'm not finding that method on the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613290.aspx), but the ASP.NET documentation is kind of fragmented right now. You might have to copy that code to an extension method, if it's not showing up for you.

Comment: ah no go, the User claims in the user are EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserClaim<string> and the ReplaceClaimAsync is a regular security Claim, maybe that's why I'm getting duplicates, since they don't quite line up... will keep digging, thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, if you debug the values, or dig up what the claim's value is from the Github source, you would be able to see if the values line up - I'm referring to the claim's identifying/type value, not the associated value you store for that claim. For instance, `ClaimTypes.Name` is actually the value `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name`. I would think that if the claims are supposed to represent the same thing, that the value would be the same even in different assemblies.

Comment: i just discovered my user.Claims in the code above is empty, so this looks like the problem; I appear to be comparing two different claims types. i'll keep digging and update a reply when i figure it out, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!